# How to interpolate a 3D image with different interpolation methods in python

Tags: python, interpolation

I am quite new in python. I have a 3D Brain image in NIFTI format (.nii.gz) and I wanna interpolate it with different methods( nearest neighbor, bilinear, Spline, ...) and compare the results. voxel size of image is 1*0.45*0.45 and I wanna make it 0.45*0.45*0.45.

I know It is quite easy task. what i have done and the problems is that: In Scipy the functions only get points but here I have an Image. and the functions which are available to get input as image, only work for 2D images. Do you have any Solution?

Comment: Have a look at [`scipy.reference.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) (maybe [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html)?)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
def rescale(data,affine):
    #compute rescaling coef
    original_resolution = [abs(affine[0,0]),abs(affine[1,1]),abs(affine[2,2])]
    target_resolution = [0.45,0.45,0.45]
    rescaling_coef = np.divide([float(i) for i in original_resolution],[float(i) for i in target_resolution])

    # X and Y dimension
    data = skimage.transform.rescale(data, (rescaling_coef[0],rescaling_coef[1]), order=1, preserve_range=True)
    # Z dimension 
    #flip axes first
    data = np.swapaxes(data,0,2)
    data = skimage.transform.rescale(data, (rescaling_coef[2],1), order=1, preserve_range=True)
    data = np.swapaxes(data,0,2)


    return data, rescaling_coef
```